# Can you see the main island of Taiwan from China?

Tags: geography

Taiwan's main island is about 100 km from China. Is it possible to see it if you are at a scenic viewing spot in China on a clear day?

This image, from a Reuters article, shows people on Pingtan Island in Fujian province, mainland China and is ambiguous. Are those islands on the far horizon (circled) the Taiwan main island or is it the Kinmen Islands (also Taiwan's territory)?

So are these hills I'm seeing 100 km out to sea or only 10 km?

[image]

Img source: https://www.reuters.com/world/asia-pacific/across-sea-taiwan-chinese-tourists-await-islands-return-2022-08-05/

Comment: I don't see the image/caption in the Aljazeera article?  At least not where I am in the UK.  Did you give the wrong source?

Comment: opps the wrong link. Edited that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the location of the photo is accurate, as Pingtan Island, it is unlikely you could see the Kinmen Islands, as they are on a different bit of coast. They certainly wouldn't be 'out at sea'.  The centre of Taiwan has elevations of over 2000 metres, which on a clear day could be visible from sea level at a range of 160 kilometres, so  that's probably what you are seeing in the picture, though it would have had to be a very clear day.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as Andy when editing the Q, looks like you mean other islands perhaps?  Best I can ascertain (using this [wiki image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_islands_of_Taiwan#/media/File:Kinmen,Matsu,Wuciou.png)), is that [your locations named are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaaE0.png)... Nederealm, did you mean differently?

Comment: Possibly, but I also wanted to know if what I was looking at is the main island